# Python and GmailAPI: How to monitor Gmail inbox to get new emails?

Tags: python, push-notification, gmail, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm writing a Python program that is trying to monitor my Gmail Inbox. Whenever a new email arrives, my program should receive the actual email content. I think the best way to do this is via Google push notifications using Gmail API.

I have made a topic and subscription, as well as manually sent and received messages using these. I have completed the Google pub-sub setup and have called watch( ) on my Inbox. If I understand this correctly, a successful watch( ) call means that my Inbox will be constantly monitored. Whenever I receive a new email, a message of the form {emailAddress, historyId} should be sent to my topic.

From this, how would I be able to actually get the email content? According to the tutorial, I would have to do something like `history.list( )` to get the "change details for the user since their last known historyId." What exactly will these "change details" be? Will they be the actual email content?

Should my next step be to set up a REST pull subscription? I am thinking of using this link:https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull so that my program can actually receive the messages sent to my topic.

Answer (score 1):

#### To get the content of an email after a push notification

As you have seen, the `users.watch` subscription will send you:

```
{
  "historyId": string,
  "expiration": string
}
```

With this `historyId` you can call the `users.history.list` endpoint to get:

```
{
  "history": [
    {
      "id": "[historyId]",
      "messages": [
        {
          "id": "[MSG ID]",
          "threadId": "[THREAD ID]"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From there you would call the `users.messages.get` endpoint to get the actual message.

NOTE: For some history IDs you will get more than one message/thread/or event per historyId, so depending on your needs you would need to handle this with your reciever.

There are a few options but you could potentially use a [cloud function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) to receive the notifications.

You could also simply set up a cron job to run your Python script every X minutes, again, depends on your specific needs.

#### References

- [users.watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users/watch)
- [users.history.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.history/list)
- [users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get)

Comment: I have a followup question: let's say I want to call ```users.history.list```. What is the actual call I would make in my code? If I type in ```users.history.list```, it says users is not defined.

Comment: Sure Darrel, though in general follow up questions are best asked in new questions (see [How to ask follow up questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)). I think if you are getting that error then the best thing for you is to follow the python quickstart to get up and running - https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python - you'll see that usually things follow the form of `results = service.users().history().list().execute()`