How to receive webhook events when a new email lands on Gmail inbox?
Is there any way to receive an event on a webhook whenever an email lands on the Gmail inbox? Just like how a webhook can be set up to receive events for Facebook Messenger messages? I am looking for relevant documentation but I am unable to find any.

Does this answer your question? Send webhook upon sending or receipt of email

Found the solution on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68154462/python-and-gmailapi-how-to-monitor-gmail-inbox-to-get-new-emails?rq=2
